# NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to call annotations

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotation

Annotations are displayed fine on the map, but when i click on one, i git this exception:

```
[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

My relevant code is this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";   
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyLocation class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapView2 dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;    
}
```

And to configure the annotations:

```
NSNumber * latitude = [[row objectAtIndex:21]objectAtIndex:1];
        NSNumber * longitude = [[row objectAtIndex:21]objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString * crimeDescription = [row objectAtIndex:17];
        NSString * address = [row objectAtIndex:13];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;            
        MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:crimeDescription address:address coordinate:coordinate] ;
        [mapView2 addAnnotation:annotation];
```

And in `MyLocation` class which holds the annotations:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _name = [name copy];
        _address = [address copy];
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377833/mkmapkit-exception-when-using-canshowcallout-on-annotation-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you tap on an annotation view, it tries to get the `length` of the annotation's `title` so it knows how wide to make the callout.

The exception you are getting indicates that somehow the `title` of that annotation is set to an `NSNull` object instead of an `NSString`.

An `NSNull` object does not have a `length` method so you get that "unrecognized selector" exception.

You haven't shown how `title` is implemented in the `MyLocation` class but I assume it returns `_name` which you are setting to `crimeDescription` (which comes from the `row` array) when creating the annotation.

Somehow, the value in the `row` array has an `NSNull` instead of an `NSString`.

If you don't need the `NSNull` values, you could change the code that sets the `row` array values so it doesn't put `NSNull`s (it could put `NSString`s like `@"Unknown"` instead).

Another option is you could modify the getter method for the `title` in the `MyLocation` class and have it return a "Unknown" `NSString` if `_name` is an `NSNull`.

For example:

```
-(NSString *)title
{
    if ([_name isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) 
        return @"Unknown";
    else
        return _name;
}
```